# Column 'sip.sip.Application.Id' is invalid in the select list

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have an query that is returning "Column 'sip.sip.Application.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" error. But i have already included that column in the group by. So i'm not sure why it's still returning this error.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
a.[ApplicationId]
,a.[Id]
,a.[CompanyId]
,c.name AS CompanyName 
,a.[CourseSIPRunId]
,ss.[AdminNo]
,count(CASE ss.StudentStatusCode WHEN 'ASG' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NoOfStudentsAllocated
,project.NoOfStudents
,project.[CourseCode]
,a.[AppStatusCode]
,appstat.AppStatusDescription
,project.[ProjectId]
,project.ProjectDescription
,a.CourseSIPRunId
,siprun.[AcadYear] + '-' + siprun.[Batch] As SIPBatch
,c.CompanyUEN
,c.PostalCode AS CompanyPostalCode
,course.CourseName
,project.[ResearchFlag]  AS ResearchFlagString
,project.MPFlag AS MPFlagString
,project.[SIPType]
,project.ProjectDescription
,case when project.[SIPType]='OSIP' then 1  else 0 END  IsOSIP 
,case when project.[ResearchFlag] ='Y' then 1 else 0 END IsResearch 
,case when project.[MPFlag] ='Y' then 1 else 0 END IsResearch 
,project.MentorProjectLeader
,a.[SpecialRequirement]
,a.[MthlyAllowance]
,a.[OtherAllowance]
,a.[DaysPerWeek]
,a.[WeekdayHoursFrom]
,a.[WeekdayHoursTo]
,a.[SaturdayHoursFrom]
,a.[SaturdayHoursTo]
,a.[SundayHoursFrom]
,a.[SundayHoursTo]
,a.[ShiftWorkRequirement]
,a.[TPContactStaffEmailId]
,a.[SIPConfirmationDate]
,a.[SIPConfirmationBy]
,a.[Remarks]
,a.[SelfSource] 
,a.[CreateSource]
,a.[CreatedDate]
,a.[SIPAllocationDate]
,a.[SIPAllocationBy]
,a.[SIPClosureDate]
,a.[SIPClosedBy]
,a.[LastUpdatedBy]
,a.[LastUpdatedDate]
,a.[AppStatusCode]
,a.[StatusReason]
,a.[OSIPCountryCode]
,a.[OSIPState]
,a.[OSIPCity]
,a.[OSIPDetails]
,a.[OverseasAssignment]
,a.[OverseasFrequency]
,a.[OverseasOtherCountry]
,a.[OverseasCountryCode]
,a.[OSIPOtherCountry]
,a.[OthersDetails]
,a.[OthersTPContactName]
,a.[OthersTPDiploma]
,a.[OthersEngagement]
,siprun.[StartDate]
,siprun.[EndDate]
,case when appotherinfo.AppOptionCode is null then 0 else 1 END IsInterviewRequired
,appotherinfo.AppOptionCode
FROM [sip].[sip].[Application] a
LEFT join  [sip].[ApplicationStatus]  appstat  on a.AppStatusCode = appstat.AppStatusCode
LEFT join [sip].[ApplicationProject] project on a.ApplicationId = project.ApplicationId
LEFT JOIN [sip].[ApplicationProjectLO] lo on project.ProjectId = lo.ProjectId
LEFT JOIN [sip].[StudentSIP] ss on ss.ProjectId = lo.ProjectId
LEFT JOIN [sip].[ApplicationProjectSupervisor] s on s.ProjectId = project.ProjectId
LEFT JOIN [sip].[Company] c on c.CompanyId = a.CompanyId
LEFT JOIN [sip].[CourseSIPRun] siprun on a.CourseSIPRunId = siprun.CourseSIPRunId
LEFT JOIN [sip].[V_SIP_COURSE] course on project.CourseCode = course.COURSECODE
LEFT JOIN [sip].[ApplicationOtherInfo] appotherinfo on appotherinfo.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId 
group by a.[ApplicationId]
```

Comment: Isn't that error message so obvious

Comment: Actually, you don't have any aggregation function at all, what's the point of the `GROUP BY`  here?

Comment: @Lamak - Actually he has.. some where hiding in middle `count(CASE ss.StudentStatusCode WHEN 'ASG' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `

Comment: @Prdp Ah, right, there is one

Answer (score 0):

You include `a.[ApplicationId]` you don't include `a.[Id]` The error message is about the 2nd one.

Comment: He has selected bunch of non-aggregate columns all those has to be added to `Group by`

Comment: @Prdp - I know, I'm trying to show him how to read an error message.